# Flicker on screen after waking PC from sleep

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, sleep

Sometimes I get flicker on my screen. It only happens, when I wake my computer from sleep. I can't do anything and is left with no other option than to restart, or turn off my computer, as it persist.
I have uploaded a short video, which shows my problem. 
Please pay attention to the monitor to the right, as it is the one which flickers:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HPr-SgDU4tY0t3aVZ1WTFBbWc/view?usp=sharing

I have recently made a fresh re-installation of windows 10, and have already installed some drivers. I have installed the latest drivers for my graphics card, but not the chipset drivers.

My specs are: 
OS: Windows 10 (version 1511, build 10586) 
CPU: Intel Core i5-3570K 3,4 Ghz (3,8 Ghz)
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z77X-D3H 
Graphics card: Nvidia Geforce GTX 660 EVGA

Could somebody please explain what causes the problem, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to your BIOS and disabling the integrated graphics video output so it always boots on dedicated graphics card. Every BIOS has a different name for it but after some digging around you should be able to find it (mine is called PEG/IGD option)

Alternatively you can try installing the Intel HD Graphics drivers, if you have not tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to disable the integrated graphics card through BIOS, as you suggested. That didn't solve my problem. 
I still get flickering screen occasionally, and last time it happened, I observed that my computer restarted after a short time.

I took a picture, when it happened last time.

[flickering_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caXlR.jpg)